# jQuery only work in index.html at some point

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, electron

the Case:

Electron Application which loads index.html first.

i have a javascript file with a jquery function that instert data in a DB with sequelize (ID insert):

```
const $ = require('jquery');
const { remote } = require('electron');
var win = remote.getCurrentWindow();
const { getCurrentWindow, globalShortcut } = require('electron').remote;
const {Sequelize, DataTypes} = require("sequelize");
const db = new Sequelize('mysql://*****:*****@******');

$(window).on("load", function () {
    console.log("loaded");

    $("#minimize").click(function () {
        console.log("minimize");
        win.minimize();
    });

    $("#maximize").click(function () {
        console.log("maximize");
        if (win.isMaximized()) {
            win.unmaximize();
        } else {
            win.maximize();
        }
    });

    $("#close").click(function () {
        console.log("close");
        win.close();
    });

    $("#insert").click(function () {
        
db  
.authenticate()
.then(() => {
  console.log('Connection successfully made.');
 

})
.catch(() => {
  console.log('Error connecting to database');

});
       
        const Parts = db.define('bestandstool', {

            // Model attributes are defined here
            Hersteller: {
              type: DataTypes.STRING,
              allowNull: false
            },
            Beschreibung: {
              type: DataTypes.STRING,
              allowNull: false
            },
            Teilenummer: {
              type: DataTypes.STRING,
              allowNull: false
            },
            Preis: {
              type: DataTypes.STRING,
              allowNull: false
            },
            SKU: {
              type: DataTypes.STRING,
              allowNull: true
            },
            
          }, {
            tableName: 'Teileliste',
            timestamps: false
          });
          db.sync({ force: false }) 
          .then(function() {
            var partinstance = Parts.build({
            Hersteller: "Volkswagen",
            Beschreibung: "Tacho, Kombiinstrument",
            Teilenummer: "3H0959876B",
            Preis: "19,95€",
            SKU: "A35"
          })
          partinstance.save()
          }) 
          
          .then(() => {
            console.log("All models were synchronized successfully.");
          }) 
          .catch(() => {
            console.log('Error syncing models.');
          
          });

    });

});

var reload = ()=>{
    getCurrentWindow().reload()
  }
  
  globalShortcut.register('F5', reload);
  globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+R', reload);
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', ()=>{
    globalShortcut.unregister('F5', reload);
    globalShortcut.unregister('CommandOrControl+R', reload);
  })
```

it does his job, when i place the button with the ID insert in the index html at exactly this point:

```
<div id="container">
  <nav>
      
      <div id="buttons">
          <div id="minimize">
            <span id="minimize-font">&mdash;</span>
          </div>
          <div id="maximize">
            <span id="size-font">&#9723;</span>
          </div>    
          <div id="close">
             <span id="close-font" >&#10005;</span>
          </div>
          <button id="insert" style="margin-top: 120px; color: black; margin-left: 150px; position: absolute; ">TEST</button>
        </div> 
    </nav>
</div>
```

but it doesn´t when i add the button to my newArticle.html:

```
  <div class="box-wrapper"> 
      <div id="articles"> 
          <div class="form">
              <from  class ="übergeben" type="submit">
                <div class= Teilenummer>
                    
                  <label for="Teilenummer">Teilenummer: </br>
              
                  <input type="text" name="Teilenummer" id="Teilenummer" style="height: 30px; width: 300px; background: #2A4A51; border-radius: 6px; border: none;" onClick="this.style.color = 'white'"/><br /><br />
              
                </div> 
                <div class= SKU>
                    
                    <label for="SKU">SKU: </br>
                
                    <input type="text" name="SKU" id="SKU" style="height: 30px; width: 100px; background: #2A4A51; border-radius: 6px; border: none;" onClick="this.style.color = 'white'"/><br /><br />
                    
                  </div> 

                  <div class= Price>
                    
                    <label for="Price">Preis: </br>
                
                    <input type="text" name="Price" id="Price" style="height: 30px; width: 100px; background: #2A4A51; border-radius: 6px; border: none;" onClick="this.style.color = 'white'"/><br /><br />
                
                  </div> 
                <div class= Hersteller>
                  <label for="Hersteller">Hersteller: </br>
                      <select name="Hersteller" id="Hersteller" style="height: 30px; width: 300px; background: #2A4A51; border-radius: 6px; border: none; color: white;">
                          <option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
                          <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
                          <option value="BMW" selected="selected">BMW</option>
                          <option value="Mercedes" selected="selected">Mercedes</option>
                          <option value="Opel" selected="selected">Opel</option>  
                      </select>
                  </label>
              </div>
              <div class=Beschreibung var=Beschreibung>
                  <label for="Beschreibung">Beschreibung: </br>
                  <input type="text" name="Beschreibung" id="Beschreibung" onClick="this.style.color = 'white'" style="height: 30px; width: 410px; background: #2A4A51; border-radius: 6px; border: none;" /><br /><br />      
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div> 
          <input id="insert" class="Eintragen-Button" type="submit" value="Anlegen " 
          onclick="values();
          document.getElementById('Teilenummer').value='';
          document.getElementById('Beschreibung').value='';
          document.getElementById('Price').value='';
          document.getElementById('SKU').value=''; "/>
          <span id="response"></span>
          
          
        
          <button class="exportieren" onclick="exportTableToExcel('tblData')">Exportieren</button>
          <button id="insert" class="exportieren">TEST</button>
      </div>
```

what i am doin wrong?? please help me!

Comment: An obvious difference here is a huge `onclick` attribute in the button's HTML, which might produce a reference error. Did you check the console?

Comment: DO NOT share your credentials when posting code! I was able to login to your database! (did not do anything, I was just curios if you actually posted real credentials).

Comment: thanks @kopz ! its not a big deal, its only a Test DB which i delete soon, no critical infos in it. But i definitelly forgot to hide the login, so thanks for the hint! the console doesn´t give me errors, i try without the onClick to be sure.

Comment: removing the onClick doesn´t solve the problem :(